# How to import .MDF.SQL file into SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have `database.mdf.sql` file I want to import into Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. I don't know how to import that file and add tables of that file into new database file.

Comment: Is it a `.mdf` file (a binary database file), or is it just a `.sql` file (text file that contains SQL statements)?? You can't have both at once..... the `.mdf` would have to be attached to SQL Server, the `.sql` just loaded and executed in SSMS

Answer (score 1):

Right click *Databases* and click *Attach*.

[More here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190209.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

USE [master]
GO
CREATE DATABASE [database_name] ON 
( FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\.mdf' ),
( FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\.ldf' )
 FOR ATTACH ;
GO